# Schedule Ionic Local Notification on iOS, Android

Tags: android, ios, ionic4

I'm using ionic4 local notification to schedule notification on daily basis. It works perfectly on time on ios but in Android with a small delay.

1. Anyone have experienced this before.

Also can I schedule local notification based on some condition. (ex; when user hasn't update something in the app, need to trigger the notification). This should be setup daily basis.